# libgdx external layout in xml file

Tags: libgdx, tablelayout

Is there a way to describe UI layouts in a libgdx application using an external (xml-) file in order to separate layout from code? Right now I'm using the table class and set up all actors inside the constructor. Ideally I'd like to just parse a layout from an xml file and get specific elements using some identifier to add event listeners etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this 3rd part library - https://github.com/peakgames/libgdx-stagebuilder